# Is it possible to make the 'no-drop' icon invisible?

Tags: javascript, css

I can drag and drop some objects using JavaScript, but when the object can't be dropped in certain areas, the visual symbol appears. Can I make this symbol invisible?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7cO22.png)

```css
.draggable {
    cursor: pointer;
}
.draggable:active {
    cursor: none; 
}
```